# as3 - render text straight to Sprite.graphics?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, text, textfield

Because I'm a terrible, bad person who likes to do things differently for no reason,
I'd love to be able to do something like mySprite.graphics.drawText(...).

As I understand things, the only way to get text currently is to create a TextField and add it as a child of mySprite. In my particular situation I'd rather not do that.

Any advice appreciated!

ooo

Comment: Why would you want to draw characters oer using a font?

Comment: i want to have a sprite with no children.

Comment: I would go with the answer Ascension Systems gave you as that will give you a "flattened" sprite with no chidlren

Comment: Good question. But wrong answer accepted (dead link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to wrap it up in a method of Sprite I would simply extend the Sprite class, add the function drawText to it. Within that method add the TextField etc. But it doesn't sound like you want that.

In which case have a look here
http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=916

They have created a collection of code that can render fonts without, well, fonts. There are disadvantages like file size, but it is possible.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this answer really does steer the OP in the wrong direction.  Another answer here is a direct and accurate method.

Comment: Just want to point out here as well, this is a perfect example of why, when you want to point to an external solution, you should paste the solution in your answer as well. That link is now dead.

Comment: So you suggest duplicating content? If the linked content is updated, should I update my answer here? If I post a link it will always be the most up to date in terms of content - in this vein, why post links anywhere? Google should just list content inline in its search results, instead of links, that would work much better. Sure the site might go down, but so might SO. I do understand the link went down (updated link here: http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=916)

Comment: this was several years ago, but as i recall that solution worked well for me. unfortunately i don't have time to go back and make sure that every answer i've accepted on SO doesn't have links which have gone dead.

Answer (score 7):

Wrong bzzzzzzzt create a new BitmapData object, create a bitmap, adding the bitmapData to it and then adding that bitmap as a child to your sprite. Example:

```
var myTextImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(textField.width, textField.height, true, 0x000000ff);

myTextImage.draw(textField);

mySprite.addChild(new Bitmap(myTextImage));

stage.addChild(mySprite);
```

I just made that code up so you'll have to adapt it but the principle should be more than clear enough to adapt it to your project.

Comment: So this way you create a textField object, write your text to it but DONT ADD IT TO YOUR SPRITE. Just draw it, then you can clear and delete the textField. What you're adding to your sprite is a bitmap with that text drawn to it.

Comment: thanks. that's an interesting approach which would probably be a bit more performant than adding the textfield itself. i should have been more clear tho - my hope was not to add a child of any sort. i guess i could draw the textfield to a bitmap data and then get that into the graphics of my sprite via beginBitmapFill.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I read it as he didn't want a textfield?

Comment: He says he doesn't want to add a textfield to the display list. This is converting a textfield into a bitmap object. After doing so, the temp textfield he uses falls out of scope and is eventually garbage collected.

Comment: Good answer. But you can also do `mySprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(myTextImage); // drawRect, endFill etc.`. That way you have a simple sprite with no children and the text is drawn to graphics.

Answer (score 6):

Create a new BitmapData object : `bitmapdata = new BitmapData(txt.width, txt.height, true, 0x000000ff);`

Draw your textfield on it : `bitmapdata.draw(txt);`

And then use graphics class and it works !

```
sprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapdata);
sprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,txt.width,txt.height);
sprite.graphics.endFill();
```

C ya

Comment: can any have full code that can be copy and paste. so i can understand your mean . thanks.