# render text to Sprite.graphics -- as3 -?

Tags: actionscript, sprite, vector-graphics, actionscript-3

Because I'm a terrible, bad person who likes to do things differently for no reason, I'd love to be able to do something like mySprite.graphics.drawText(...).

As I understand things, the only way to get text currently is to create a TextField and add it as a child of mySprite. In my particular situation I'd rather not do that.

Any advice appreciated!

ooo

Comment: You may be bad. But are you bad enough to create your own class of drawable text? Not that hard really. Just create little Sprites containing the x-y coordinates of points that 'spell-out' various letters in drawn lines inside of Shape objects. Then call on that class to draw text into your sprite. Go for it, bad boy!

Comment: @Craig Like I said in my answer, that would result in display objects which would have to be added as children. In this case you could be adding hundreds of children onto the stage to replace 1. I guess memory-wise this could be MARGINALLY efficient though (marginally as in, wouldn't make much of a difference) since it'd have less properties and events than the TextField object per string of text. And even still, that really depends on the OP's memory management abilities because it could turn out the opposite way and result in a whole bunch of memory leaks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [as3 - render text straight to Sprite.graphics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722561/as3-render-text-straight-to-sprite-graphics)

Comment: Hmm. Reposting a question with exact wording might not get you very far from what was once replied.

Comment: -1 pt. for zero effort in framing your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextField` class inherits the `InteractiveObject` class which inherits the `DisplayObject` class. Display objects cannot be displayed unless they are programmed to, which is what `addChild` does.

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html for more information.

Also, from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/states/AddChild.html -

> The AddChild class adds a child display object, such as a component,
>   to a container as part of a view state. You use this class in the
>   overrides property of the State class.

Comment: No, there is a way to do just what OP wants.

Comment: @Vesper Please teach me how to add things to the stage without adding it as a display object.

Comment: I have linked the question which has answers on how to do that. Actually, `drawText` reference means that the text drawn will be static, so you can call `draw(textfield)` once and call it a day.

Comment: @Vesper Oh, well in my understanding of the question I thought the OP wanted a way to add a TextField to the stage without using addChild. Sorry for the misread. I'll keep my answer here anyway for informative value if that's fine?